# Requests and urllib3 exceptions in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

Absolutely stumped because I've never had such an issue when using python.
Briefly, I used the code below:

```
import requests
import json

webhook_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/webhook' #'https://webhook.site/580151cf-1c53-488c-a325-dbc76f12a8c5'

data = {'name': 'Mathieu',
        'Channel URL': 'blablabla'}

r = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

However, I received this HUGE error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 395, in request
    self.endheaders()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libh\http\client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 243, in connect
    self.sock = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F901B551C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhook (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F901B551C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhook (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F901B551C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Comment: `Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Comment: When I use webhook_url = 'https://webhook.site/580151cf-1c53-488c-a325-dbc76f12a8c5', I get :

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)